# How to properly run an API GET request with ODBC access?

Tags: r, rodbc, plumber

Im trying to create an API that receives an ID, queries a MSSQL database and returns back a result.

```
#* @apiTitle  IdCx
#* @apiDescription A test
#* @get /IdCx
#* 

apiFn <- function(id) { 
  require(odbc)
  require(glue)
  
  dbcon  <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                      ,dsn = "test"
                      ,database = "testDB"
                      ,uid    = user1
                      ,pwd    = pass1
                      ,Trusted_Connection= "No"
                      ,encoding = "UTF-8"
  )
  IdCx = dbGetQuery(dbcon, glue_sql('SELECT max (CC.IdCx) 
                                          FROM table CC
                                          where IdA in ({id})
                                          '))
 
  as.numeric(IdCx)
  
}
```

After creating the R file `main.R`, I execute it:

```
apiTest <- pr("main.R")
pr_run(apiTest)
```

But I get this error

```
{

    "error": "500 - Internal server error",
    "message": "Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'statement' in selecting a method for function 'dbGetQuery': error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'dbQuoteLiteral': el argumento \".con\" is missing, with no default\n"

}
```

[image]

But if I deliberately insert a fixed `id=1365350` inside the code (just for testing), the API will return a correct result

```
#* @apiTitle  IdCx
#* @apiDescription A test
#* @get /IdCx
#* 

apiFn<- function(id) { 
  require(odbc)
  require(glue)
  
  id=1365350
  dbcon  <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                      ,dsn = "venus"
                      ,database = "DWHICV"
                      ,uid    = Sys.getenv("sql_reportes_id")
                      ,pwd    = Sys.getenv("sql_reportes_pw")
                      ,Trusted_Connection= "No"
                      ,encoding = "UTF-8"
  )
  IdCx = dbGetQuery(dbcon, glue_sql('SELECT max (CC.IdCx) 
                                          FROM hceCxCirugia CC
                                          where IdAtencion in ({id})
                                          '))
 
  as.numeric(IdCx)
  
}
```

Including `#* @param IdA` wont fix the error

[image: dd]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with including `#* @param id`

Comment: Yes. Same error still shows

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't test your case as it is not reproducible

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Eventhough I never used the parameter `.con` inside the `glue_sql` function when running it from RStudio, apparently is mandatory when using plumber API.

```
  IdCx = dbGetQuery(dbcon, glue_sql('SELECT max (CC.IdCx) 
                                          FROM table CC
                                          where IdA in ({id})
                                          ,.con = dbcon))
```